# Swapping integrals and limits

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f(x)$ such that

$$f(tx)e^{-x^2}dx$$

is integrable on $[-\infty, \infty]$ $\forall t>0$. Also, $f(x)$ is continuous around 0.

I'm trying to prove that

$$\lim_{t\to0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(tx)e^{-x^2}dx = f(0)\sqrt\pi$$

Now, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$ goes to $\sqrt\pi$, so my guess is that the limit and integral should commute, however I can't find a way of showing that. I've tried using the dominated convergence theorem, but I can't come up with a good sequence $f_n$ such that I can find an integrable dominating function.

EDIT: Half my post text was lost when copying over; updated the body.

The obvious $f_n(x) = f(x/n)$ does not work, as I cannot seem to find a reasonable dominating function $G$. Consider $f$ as a function which is mostly zero, apart from spikes at integer positions. These spikes have height $e^{(x+1)^2}$ and width $\epsilon_x$ which vanishes quickly enough such that $f(tx)e^{-x^2}$ integrable. If we look for a dominating function $G(x) > |f_n(x)| = f(x/n) \forall x, n$, we have that for any fixed point x, it's true that $G(x) > f(x/n)$ for all n, i.e $G(x) > f(y) \forall y \in (0, x)$, so $G(x) = \max_{y < x} f(y)$. This makes $G$ be a stepwise function which overapproximates $e^{x^2}$, so $G(x)e^{-x^2}$ not integrable.

So I am not sure how to use DCT effectively in this case.

Any tips or corrections for my reasoning are appreciated.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by the integral being absolutely convergence for $t \geq 0$? If your integral is supposd to be a lebesgue integral (which I guess it is, because you want to use dominated convergence), then every integrable function is absolutely integrable.

Comment: Sorry, I was imprecise what I meant. Updated it, does that clear things up?

Comment: Not really... Lebesgue integrability requires that $f^+$ and $f^-$ (i.e., the positive and negative parts) exists *individually*, so $f$ being integrable always implies $|f|$ being integrable. So "absolutely integrable" really is the same as "integrable" - do you maybe just mean to forbid the integral to take the value $\infty$ or $-\infty$? Because that *is* allowed for lebesgue integrals, at least in some contexts.

Comment: Oh, right, strengthened the condition for the integral to be convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, for any fixed $M$, it is clear that $$
  \int_{-M}^M f(tx)e^{-x^2} dx \to f(0)\int_{-M}^M e^{-x^2} dx \text{ as $t \to 0$}
$$

> This works because for every $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a $\delta$ such that $$
> f(0) - \frac{\epsilon}{4M} \leq f(u) \leq f(0) + \frac{\epsilon}{4M}
> \text{ for $|u| \leq \delta$}
> $$
>   by the continuity of $f$ around $0$ and then $$
>   \left|\int_{-M}^M f(tx)e^{-x^2} dx - \int_{-M}^M f(0) e^{-x^2} dx\right| \leq \epsilon
> $$
>   for $|Mt| \leq \delta$, i.e. for $t \leq \frac{\delta}{M}$.

You also have that $$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(tx)e^{-x^2} = \lim_{M \to \infty} \int_{-M}^M f(tx)e^{-x^2} dx \text{,}
$$
because you can use dominated convergence on
$\int_{-M}^M f(tx)e^{-x^2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{[-M,M]} f(tx)e^{-x^2} dx$.

It thus comes down to whether $$
  \lim_{t \to 0^+} \lim_{M \to \infty} \int_{-M}^M f(tx)e^{-x^2} dx = 
  \lim_{M \to \infty} \lim_{t \to 0^+} \int_{-M}^M f(tx)e^{-x^2} dx \text{.}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first step is equivalent to $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_{-M}^{M} f(tx) e^{x^2} = \int_{-M}^{M} \lim_{t\to 0^+} f(tx) e^{x^2} dx$$ How does one justify that, as it seems to have the same issue as what I mentioned in my initial post, i.e. not sure how to apply DCT.

Comment: I added an argument for why this works.

Comment: Many thanks. I was getting too hung up on DCT to consider a simple epsilon-delta argument.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson You still need to show that the two limits converge in the last line, though... BTW, I wonder if this wouldn't become easier if you substitute $v = xt$ in the integral. That would put the influence of $t$ into the damping factor, which you know explicitly, instead of into $f$, which we know nothing about...

Comment: Yup, I was just looking for a hint to help me get out of the rut I found myself into, I'll have a think and finish the argument up.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson If you finish the proof, please post it as an answer, or edit mine to include it.